# Does anyone know what the most efficient format to transfer content to an iOS app would be?

Tags: ios

I have a series of text files that have been extracted from html and include hrefs and some minor formatting. I'd like to minimize the download size to the iOS device while maintaining as much formatting as possible. The presentation can probably just be handled within the swift app.

Any thoughts would be really appreciated!

Comment: Zip archive?...

Comment: Hmm... I guess that would be the smart way wouldn't it. For small file sizes the decompression and presentation would probably be pretty quick too. Good idea!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above answers and the reddit post I made on the same topic [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/523hlc/does_anyone_know_what_the_most_efficient_format/)

Courtesy of u/chriswaco 
"NSURLSession should support HTTP GET with Accept-Encoding: gzip, which is the easiest way to get reasonably decent compression if the server supports it."

It appears that the most effective way to handle this is with gzip. I am going to implement some server side file reduction as well. If anyone has any thoughts on the best way to reformat html for presentation in a client side app please throw your thoughts in!